# Do I need a star's permission to write a fiction TV series inspired but not exactly as his life?

Tags: copyright, legal, screenwriting

I want to write a fiction TV series inspired by a true love story between a star and his fans except that I'm going to represent the fans as an actual female character and make it a romantic series. Also this star has had a girl making up false rumors (scanlde) about him and a I want to include that in my TV series although I still don't know whether to use the same scandle or makeup another one according to what the story needs. So I want to know: Do I need that star's permission first to write that series?

PS: I also wish he plays the main role (the star) in it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a *writing* problem per se. You might consider asking over on our sister site [law.se]. Also, please specify a jurisdiction.

Comment: Hi Michael, what is a jurisdiction? I will try to ask on Law site. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jurisdiction#Noun (or just plug the word into your favorite search engine and you'll likely get some useful hits near the top)

Comment: Write it as fanfic. Write it with the actual actor and get it out of your system. It will be truer to what you really want to write, you will like it more, and — since you *cannot* publish it for money and can only post or publish it as a derivative work — permission is not really an issue.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you:

http://www.betternovelproject.com/blog/real-people/

I don't write for TV but a couple of my friends do and according to them, getting an agent and selling a TV series is an extremely difficult and competitive process. Even if you manage to secure an agent and they manage to sell the rights to your TV drama, the chances of it actually getting made are desperately low. The reason being that rights are bought for a set period (perhaps 5 years) and during that time production companies run into untold difficulties until the rights return to the writer and you have to start again.

When I went through a low patch with novel writing, I considered screenwriting instead and they talked me out of it, saying that publishing is far easier (and I thought publishing was hard enough!). That's not to say you shouldn't keep trying! Always follow your dreams!

However, the reason for pointing this out is to say that it's a hard enough business as it is, and if you write something that has the potential to lead a production company into litigation, you're stacking the odds against yourself when the odds are stacked enough as it is.

Does it have to be a real-life star? Couldn't you write your story using your star as an inspiration for a fictional character, making sure you change enough details to make them unrecognisable and the events that happen to them seem unconnected?

Your story could be just as good, just as marketable.

I'm an old broad, so if you're a youngster you won't have heard of this movie, but look at A Star Is Born (I'm a big fan of the Barbra Streisand and Kris Kristofferson version). The screenwriter creates a completely fictional star (albeit reminiscent of any number of real-life rock stars) and watching it, you truly believe he's real. It's handled so well, I don't feel cheated because that character isn't based on a real-life celebrity.

If I were in your shoes, I would remove as many obstacles from my path to success as I possibly could before starting my journey. It's a hard enough journey as it is.

Good luck! Hope we see your show on TV one day!

Comment: Hi GGx, actually I'm writing this show for my favorite Korean star and for Korean drama industry. This star had the most difficult time dealing with a gold digger but also had his fans to help him through it so if it can't be really obviously about him and us, the story won't be worth writing. I want to show the beauty of how he made his fans' lives better and how his fans helped him through this scandle which can be a career destroyer in Korean society.

Comment: There was a sitcom that got made in America, and it revolved around Jennifer Grey and how she struggles with getting acting jobs after her nose job made her unrecognizable.  I always wondered how this would have played out if they managed to sell the story idea, but couldn't get Jennifer to play her part.  Sorry, not exactly helpful unless you can get ahold of that show's writers.

Comment: I read that article before but it doesn't answer my question about plot structure inspired by that star's real life. Also my star character is not 100% like the real star I'm writing for, it's about 95% I'm even going to give him a different name.

Comment: I read that article before but it doesn't answer my question about plot structure inspired by that star's real life. Also my star character is not 100% like the real star I'm writing for, it's about 95%

Comment: @Yostina I’m not a lawyer, you would need to check Korean privacy, publicity and defamation laws, but I would say, even if you managed to get his permission to write about him, you are still potentially on rocky ground. If your character is 95% like this real star, he is going to be recognisable in your book and he will be able to prove that in court.

Comment: You are (presumably) then going to fabricate things he hasn't ever said or done? All it takes is for him to take objection to one thing that you write about him, that he feels defames his character in some way, and you could end up in court.

The gold digger you are portraying will also (probably) be able to prove that you are writing about her and could take you to court for defamation if you fabricate things she hasn’t said or done. The general public also have privacy and defamation rights so she could sue you as well.

Comment: Finally, you will be using his celebrity status to sell your books without giving him credit as the main character or paying him. 

I'd say you need a good lawyer!!

Comment: No GGx, you got me wrong. Basically what I want to write is the story of how fans stood by this star's side through the difficult times. I will mix things from reality and my imagination and it is my intent that this star play the role I created for him which will be about 95% of his real character in real life in terms of hobbies, how he acts and reacts to certain things...etc.I will give this star character a different name form his real name. It's a totally fictional story except that I'm going to touch on the subject of gold diggers which really happened in his life in a fictional way too.

Comment: The whole TV series will be symbolic to what happened to him in real life and to what happened to other stars too. I came to a conclusion that I will contact him since I will need him to play the main role (the star) because if he doesn't like the role, there will be no use to write it.

Comment: @Yostina I think I understand what you're trying to do and you have absolutely come to the right conclusion, you need his permission. I would still get legal advice once it's written though, esp. when you "mix things from reality" that depict **real** people. Good luck!